# jgit: fetch the note content of every note in a git repository

Tags: git, jgit

Is there a way to fetch the note content of every note in a git repository using jgit. I tried couple of approaches but none of it seem to work.

The below approach, doest list the note content nor the commit ID.

```
    FileRepository repo;
    try {
        repo = new FileRepository("C:\\example\\repos");
        RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);
        NoteMap map = NoteMap.newEmptyMap();
        Ref ref = repo.getRef("refs/notes/commits");

        if (ref != null) {
            RevCommit notesCommit = walk.parseCommit(ref.getObjectId());
            map = NoteMap.read(walk.getObjectReader(), notesCommit);
            map.getNote(notesCommit.getId());
            Iterator<Note> it = map.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println(it.next());
            }
```

Please let me know?

Comment: Maybe something in https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/notes/NoteMapTest.java can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jgit provides a [ListNotes](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/ListNotesCommand.html) command which can provide either specific or all notes in the repository. From there you can then read the not-content.

You can see an example of how this is used at the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) in the Snippet [ListNotes.java](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListNotes.java).

The actual data can then be fetched by a normal Blob-read because notes are stored as normal blobs like file contents, i.e.

```
ObjectLoader loader = repository.open(note.getData());
loader.copyTo(System.out);
```

Comment: The above approach only lists the SHA-1's and not the actual note contents.. Is there an approach which fetches the actual note content and not just the SHA-1..

Comment: The line of code 
    note.getData().getName()
only fetches the commit ID of the note, but not the actual note content. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an explanation how the data is read from the note-blob and also updated the sample in jgit-cookbook now.

Comment: Awesome, just one last question, how to get the content of a note, for a given commit ID?

Comment: The only way I found is to iterate over all notes and check for the commit via the following:

if(!note.getName().equals(head.getObjectId().getName())) { ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the note contents as a string without printing it on a standard output(console), you can use following lines of code.

```
ObjectLoader loader = repository.open(note.getData());
byte[] bytes = loader.getBytes();
String s = new String(bytes);
```